# C++ method for non class or struct

Tags: c++

Is there any way in C++ to have a method for variable which is not a class or struct? Suppose I have a defined type `dogs` for convenience.

```
using dogs = std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>;
dogs d;
```

Now, what I want to achieve is to have a method, e.g. `print()` which operated on the `dogs` type variable `d`.

```
d.print();
```

Comment: Actually, std::unordered_map also is a class.

Comment: Is inheriting (extending) from `dogs` allowed?

Comment: You can also print with `cout << d` by creating a suitable `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const dogs& d)` function. This can be done with a free function without creating another class.

Comment: Anything is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `d.print()` means invocation of the method `print` that `std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>` actually hasn't. You can't add new methods to an existing class in C++ in contrast to e.g. Python because C++ is a statically typed language. The only way to add new method to a class is creating a new class that inherits to the interested class like

```
struct dogs : std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>{
    void print();
};
... // define your dogs::print();

void foo()
{
    dogs d;
    d.print(); //now you can use it
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way in C++ to have a method for variable which is not a class or struct?

You can have free functions which don't require a class. Methods a.k.a. member functions can be defined only for classes.

> ```
> std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>
> ```

`std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>` is in fact a class. And it has member functions. But you may not define more member functions for this class, nor other classes from the standard library.

You could define a free function such as this:

```
void print(const std::unordered_map<std::string, dog>&);
```

Which you can call like this:

```
print(d);
```